# How do I reload data and update a bound element after a user clicks a button?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

Why is it that when I click 'Random', the information in the template isn't reset and the data isn't update?

I have data that I want to display after a REST endpoint is successfully reached. The REST data that's returned is a random database record, so I don't need to worry about randomizing my request or anything. I only need to reach the server via that URL. In this case, the URL is: `localhost:8000/api/verses/0`

My handlebars template looks like this:

**app/templates/verses.hbs**

```
<div id="panel">

  <h3>{{model.reference_number}}
  <h3>{{model.body}}</h3>
  <button {{action "getAnotherVerse"}}>Random</button>

 </div>
{{outlet}}
```

So, when the 'Random' button is clicked, the following should be invoked:

**app/controllers/verses.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    actions: {
        getAnotherVerse: function() {
            this.get('model').reload();
            // This is where the text should be reset to the new data.
        }
    }
});
```

**app/routers/verses.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.store.find('verse', '0');
    }
});
```

Comment: Is AJAX GET request fired when you use `this.get('model').reload()`? Does it send you correct info? Do you use only one model for all random values coming and then update this model with new data? Why do you load only record with `0` id in your `Route`?

Comment: @Daniel Whenever I go to /api/verses/0, a random database object is returned with all the info I need.

Comment: Check in Chrome Developer Tools, Network card if request to server is fired  when you call `getAnotherVerse` method. Can you also give example of data received from server?

Comment: @Daniel  The request fired successfully (200). An example of the data: http://pastebin.com/vxeyCUik  When I go to the index, the data is displayed correctly. When I refresh the page, the data is, in fact, random (it's based on the data received when the endpoint is hit. I just need ember to hit the server again when the button is pressed and reflect those changes.

Comment: Ok, my last question is - when you call `this.get('model').reload();` request is fired to which URL? Check in Developer Tools please, because I think I might now where's the issue.

Comment: @Daniel Now I get a 200 when I press the 'Random' button, which should be a good thing. However, the data displayed isn't showing what should be new data.

Comment: I asked about URL where `this.get('model').reload();` fires its request to fetch new data when you click `getAnotherVerse`.

Comment: @Daniel Ahh, it fires at /api/verses/1

Comment: You know the issue now ; ) It's because of id being passed from server.

Comment: @Daniel Yeah! Now, how do I prevent ember from doing that so that whenever I press the button, it just fires the original request and gets the data back?

Comment: Please try my original first answer and see if it's working. It should because it resets model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you fire `getAnotherVerse` you just take the current record(`model`) and simply reload it to fetch its latest data. I guess you want to call `model` method of your route once again, so model will be reset and you'll get brand new record from your server.

Move `getAnotherVerse` to your `VersesRoute` where you specify model for `VersesController` and try following code:

```
# app/routes/verses.js
model: function() {
  return this.store.find('verse', '0');
},
actions: {
  getAnotherVerse: function() {
    this.refresh(); # beforeModel, model, afterModel, setupController will re-fire
  }
}
```

If this still doesn't work, please try this:

```
# app/routes/verses.js
model: function() {
  return this.store.fetch('verse', '0');
},
actions: {
  getAnotherVerse: function() {
    this.store.unloadAll('verse'); # I assume `verse` is your Model name
    this.refresh(); # beforeModel, model, afterModel, setupController will re-fire
  }
}
```

Comment: I updated the router to give you a better picture. The endpoint returns a random database object, if that helps you understand what I'm working with. I just need that new info each time the button is clicked.

Comment: You're the man! It works! I had to unloadAll() the entire time. The second code is what works. Thank you SO much!

Answer (score 0):

Your telling Ember Data to find the record with id = 0. Just guessing that your API endpoint is treating `0` as a special case and returning a record that does have an actual `id`.

Because Ember Data is using an identity map under the hood I'm guessing that when you call reload the data is creating a new record in the store. And therefore isn't triggering updates on the record that is being used for the model.

A better approach would be to just use

```
var that = this;
Ember.$.get('localhost:8000/api/verses/0')
  .then(function(data) {
    that.set('model', data);
  });
```

You could push the `data` into the store too http://emberjs.com/guides/models/pushing-records-into-the-store/ and then it would be available if you need to find it by id later.

Another approach would be to create a custom adapter / serializer that could hide some of this, really depends on how your using ember data outside of this use case.

Comment: Daniel answered my question, it turns out. All I had to do was `this.store.unloadAll('verse');` before a refresh. Thanks anyway!